# Wrapped Text Search?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers

This is an excerpt from a PDF generated with PDFLaTeX (3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 from TeX Live 2012):

```
when the disease is still spreading undetected and mitigation
measures are not being made.
```

When I search for "mitigation" in my PDF viewer, it finds the word. When I search for "measures", it finds the word. When I search for "mitigation measures" it doesn't find anything.

Maybe this is a thing with my PDF viewer, but I'd think there would be a way to generate output searchable by even a line-limited viewer.

Is there a way to tell PDFLaTeX to improve the searchability of the PDF's text?

Comment: Since you mention that this *might* be PDF-viewer specific. Have you tried any other? A quick search in Adobe Reader works fine across a line break.

Comment: Works fine in OSX Preview as well.  What PDF viewer *are* you using?

Comment: evince in Linux. I'm going to try to get ahold of another reader to test that aspect of the problem.

Comment: It can be reopened if it would be a general issue, independent of the reader.